# Are properties and methods presented in Reference Documentation of Cesium-js, defined in CZML language?

Tags: cesiumjs, czml

I am using cesium to visualize my transportation problem, I find working with CZML is much easier for me. But I found so many good methods and properties such as `VelocityOrientationProperty` or `SampledPositionProperty` which seems are not applicable in CZML, Am I right? Is there any good way that I can use such these methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SampledPositionProperty` is the main one that Entities use when specifying a position that changes over time.  I've included a CZML snippet below that shows a truck driving over a bridge using only a 2-point SampledPositionProperty.

The `VelocityOrientationProperty` is much newer ([introduced in March](https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/pull/2604)), and is not yet wired into CZML.  Currently the only way in CZML is to have the server pre-calculate the orientation over time, and send down a list of quaternions.  This is probably on a roadmap to fix at some future point, you can try asking on the mailing list.  In the past I've also seen clients get the CZML from the server, and then loop over the entities that need `VelocityOrientationProperty` and add it in manually there.

The `position` property at the very bottom of this CZML example has options that line up with the `SampledPositionProperty` class, and that class will be used here.

```
[{
    "id" : "document",
    "version" : "1.0",
    "clock" : {
      "interval" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z/2012-08-04T16:02:00Z",
      "currentTime" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z",
      "multiplier" : 1,
      "range" : "LOOP_STOP",
      "step" : "SYSTEM_CLOCK_MULTIPLIER"
    }
}, {
    "id" : "Vehicle",
    "availability" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z/2012-08-04T16:02:00Z",
    "billboard" : {
        "eyeOffset" : {
            "cartesian" : [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
        },
        "horizontalOrigin" : "CENTER",
        "image" : "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABgAAAAYCAYAAADgdz34AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAEISURBVEhLvVXBDYQwDOuojHKj8LhBbpTbpBCEkZsmIVTXq1RVQGrHiWlLmTTqPiZBlyLgy/KSZQ5JSHDQ/mCYCsC8106kDU0AdwRnvYZArWRcAl0dcYJq1hWCb3hBrumbDAVMwAC82WoRvgMnVMDBnB0nYZFTbE6BBvdUGqVqCbjBIk3PyFFR/NU7EKzru+qZsau3ryPwwCRLKYOzutZuCL6fUmWeJGzNzL/RxAMrUmASSCkkAayk2IxPlwhAAYGpsiHQjbLccfdOY5gKkCXAMi7SscAwbQpAnKyctWyUZ6z8ja3OGMepwD8asz+9FnSvbhU8uVOHFIwQsI3/p0CfhuqCSQuxLqsN6mu8SS+N42MAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
        "pixelOffset" : {
            "cartesian2" : [0.0, 0.0]
        },
        "scale" : 0.8,
        "show" : true,
        "verticalOrigin" : "BOTTOM"
    },
    "path" : {
        "material" : {
            "solidColor" : {
                "color" : {
                    "rgba" : [255, 255, 0, 255]
                }
            }
        },
        "width" : 5.0,
        "show" : true
    },
    "position" : {
        "interpolationAlgorithm" : "LAGRANGE",
        "interpolationDegree" : 1,
        "epoch" : "2012-08-04T16:00:00Z",
        "cartesian" : [0.0, 1254962.0093268978, -4732330.528380746, 4074172.505865612,
                       120.0, 1256995.7322857284, -4732095.2154790815, 4073821.2249589274]
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be broader than just those two examples.

I too find it great to work with CZML. However currently https://github.com/AnalyticalGraphicsInc/cesium/wiki/CZML-Content is a little out-of-date, e.g. i found an example that uses "rectangle.wsenDegrees" but not documented.

I read an Issue comment somewhere that indicated that CZML would get some further attention soon.

In the meantime, the [Sandcastle](https://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/) is now updated to include a gallery of new CZML examples.